# Symfony 2.5 + FosUser not send emails for restore the pasword

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

I've the project in my LocalHost, and I can restore my password with email in Dev mode , but when I try it in the Server Production never send the email.

I have the same parameters and configuration in dev that in prod.

Config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:  
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main 
user_class: Path_____________
from_email:
    address:        email@example.com
    sender_name:    NameEmail
```

Parameters.yml

```
parameters:  
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp._______.es
mailer_user: _____@_____.__
mailer_password: *******
locale: en
secret: secretsecret
...
```

Comment: Are you using the same mail server and same OS on your local development and production system?

Comment: in dev I use Windows and the server use Linux

Comment: @Gannon which version of linux on your server ? Try something like this in the linux terminal to see which version : cat /proc/version

Comment: the logs it's empty , but I use swiftmailer of Symfony . This is not a mailserver? Thanks